# Douglas Crockford on Class Free OOP in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

Douglas Crockford has a really good talk on "The Better Parts" of ES6. Among other things, he [encourages a move away from prototypal inheritance in favor of class free OOP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0&t=6m).

Here he says he stopped using `new`, `Object.create`, and `this`, but didn't really explain an alternative. Could anyone fill me in on how that might look?

Comment: Here's an article with some good examples: https://dannyfritz.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/class-free-object-oriented-programming/

Comment: If you go to about [*23:00*](http://youtu.be/PSGEjv3Tqo0?t=23m) he tells you.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Well, it's hard to characterize his position as "renouncing object-oriented programming", when he himself says his current approach is exactly "class-free **object-oriented programming**", and his entire approach is based on objects encapsulating data and behavior, which sounds an awful lot like object-oriented programming to me. I also see little in that particular presentation, at least, which indicates he is taking any strong position in favor of a functional style of programming.

Comment: @HMR he denounces ES6 classes at [5:00](http://youtu.be/PSGEjv3Tqo0?t=5m)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should watch the whole video, he explains it at [later in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0#t=1395).

```
function constructor(spec) {
  let {member} = spec,
      {other}  = other_constructor(spec),
      method   = function () {
        // accesses member, other, method, spec
      };

  return Object.freeze({
      method,
      other
  });
}
```

It's the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) returning a [frozen object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Comment: Why is it necessary to freeze the object? Doesn't this stop inheritance?

Comment: @Quinten: He is freezing the object that reveals the API , i.e. the anonymous object with pointers to the object's methods.  So I believe this is like freezing the interface.

Comment: @SMeaden, i think i was missing the point that you deconstruct another object to inherit it's methods. I read in his book (How javascript works) that the freezing is done mainly for security reasons, so the methods cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

## Example

- Approach A: Objects w/ Functions

  - This is faster than classes / prototypes (there's no extra table lookups on the functions, such as `greet`), but may use (mostly negligible) more memory (a pointer per function, essentially).
- Approach B: Value Objects (pure JSON, no functions on the object)

  - The big (capital P) `Person` has the methods (such as `save`) - the only downside to this is that you always wrap the function you want to use if it needs to be in a callback and preserve context.

Neither of these approaches require arrow functions or bind or anything like that, which means that your code will both parse and run faster.

```js
var Person = {};

Person.create = function (tmpl) {
  var person = {
    name: tmpl.name || 'No Name',
    age: tmpl.age || 0,
    
  };

  // Approach A
  person.greet = function (other) {
    return `Hello ${other.name}! I'm ${person.name}!`;
  };

  return person;
};

// Approach B
Person.save = async function (p) {
  if (p.id) {
    await request({
      method: "PUT",
      url: `/api/people/${p.id}`,
      json: p
    });
    return p;
  }

  var resp = await request({
    method: "POST",
    url: `/api/people/`,
    json: p
  });
  p = resp.body;
  return p;
};
```

You can combine the approaches, but if you at all incorporate Approach A just be sure that your constructor faithfully reproduces objects with JSON with the required functions and without overwriting existing values with default values.