# How do I share "constructor" functionality in Crockford's new constructor pattern?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've watched the video from [this question on class-free OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595749) several times now, and I'm having trouble applying this to a real world example.

Crockford's new constructor pattern looks like this:

```
function constructor(spec) {
  let {member} = spec,
      {other}  = other_constructor(spec),
      method   = function () {
        // accesses member, other, method, spec
      };

  return Object.freeze({
      method,
      other,
  });
}
```

Where `spec` is an options hash and the resulting object exposes methods which close over all of the internal members. Ignoring the destructuring (as this can be done in long-form in present-day JS,) **how do I apply this pattern in a real world example?**

I currently have a library with a base class `Module(model, id)` where `model` is some bootstrapping data.

```
// constructor, original flavor
function Module(model, id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.model = model;
}
```

I then have several flavors of modules which inherit from this parent `Module`. Under Crockford's pattern, I would instead have this as a "constructor":

```
// constructor, Crockford's Cool Ranch
function module(spec) {
    let id = spec.id,
        model = spec.model;

    return Object.freeze({});
}
```

How do I use Crockford's pattern (which doesn't seem to use inheritance at all, but rather composing an object from multiple sources) to **share this basic construction among multiple flavors of modules**?

*I know that `id` and `model` will become local variables in the "constructor" of each module; I am essentially asking how to avoid repeating `model = spec.model` for each flavor of module using Crockford's pattern.*

Comment: I'd also like to be the first to point out here that, on that other question, I got credit for an answer I don't understand. :(

Comment: you can't. you're mixing metaphors here; the 3rd box is not like the 2nd box at all. the 3rd returns a blank object with no proto, the 2nd returns a custom object with a proto and 2 owns. crockford's returns a non-proto object with _n_ owns. it's like having the simplicity of  prototype (getting a bunch of methods at once, in that case from _other_ instead of _prototype_), but without iterating them all like we do now via extend() tools.

Comment: @dandavis I know that in the 2nd box the properties are exposed and in the 3rd they are private. If we ignore the 2nd box entirely, is your answer the same? There is no way to avoid repeating the setup code necessary for assigning private members in each flavor of the module?

Comment: you can put them in prototype today, or include them in the output destructing tommorow. or extend them via iteration today. lastly, and perhaps best, you can define "inherited" properties via a separate base "constructor", and base.apply(this,arguments)/base.call(this) up top in the particular. that way you get lots of owns, no iteration, and wide compat. the apply() w/arguments is nice because it more closely matches the way other language pass init args to sub-constructors. they can also be reffered to lexically in own methods, something crockford's makes easy.

Comment: @dandavis can you give an example of that as an answer? I recognize that this object relationship is neither prototypical nor classical inheritance, and I'm trying to understand how to use it correctly (and even how to think about it correctly, as evidenced by my confusion.)

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what you're after. do you want your code as ES6, or crockford's code as ES5 setup with your other stuff? or the ES3 stuff i mentioned about call/apply fit to your code?

Comment: @dandavis Crockford's as ES5 is probably closest to what I'm looking for, although honestly all 3 sound like they would be helpful. I'm trying to understand how to write DRY modules with properly scoped variables using composition/extension instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 8):

What Crockford calls “class-free inheritance” is actually still prototypal inheritance. Actually, there are [two](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#toc_8) [types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) of prototypal inheritance mechanisms:

1. Prototypal inheritance via delegation (a.k.a. differential inheritance).
2. Prototypal inheritance via cloning (a.k.a. concatenative inheritance).

## An example of differential prototypal inheritance

This is how I traditionally write object-oriented JavaScript code:

```js
var Aircraft = defclass({
    constructor: function (model, speed) {
        this.model = model;
        this.speed = speed;
    },
    describeAircraft: function () {
        alert("The " + this.model + " flies at " + this.speed + " speed.");
    }
});

var FighterAircraft = extend(Aircraft, {
    constructor: function (model, speed, radar) {
        Aircraft.call(this, model, speed);
        this.radar = radar;
    },
    describeFighterAircraft: function () {
        this.describeAircraft();
        alert("It has a " + this.radar + " radar signature.");
    }
});

var superFlanker = new FighterAircraft("Super Flanker", "Mach 2.25", "low");

superFlanker.describeFighterAircraft();
```

```html
<script>
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

function extend(constructor, properties) {
    var prototype = Object.create(constructor.prototype);
    for (var name in properties) prototype[name] = properties[name];
    return defclass(prototype);
}
</script>
```

## An example of concatenative prototypal inheritance

This is how Crockford advocates to write object-oriented JavaScript code:

```js
var superFlanker = FighterAircraft({
    model: "Super Flanker",
    speed: "Mach 2.25",
    radar: "low"
});

superFlanker.describeFighterAircraft();
```

```html
<script>
function Aircraft(spec) {
    var model = spec.model;
    var speed = spec.speed;

    function describeAircraft() {
        alert("The " + model + " flies at " + speed + " speed.");
    }

    return Object.freeze({
        model: model,
        speed: speed,
        describeAircraft: describeAircraft
    });
}

function FighterAircraft(spec) {
    var aircraft = Aircraft(spec);
    var model    = spec.model;
    var speed    = spec.speed;
    var radar    = spec.radar;

    function describeFighterAircraft() {
        aircraft.describeAircraft();
        alert("It has a " + radar + " radar signature.");
    }

    return Object.freeze({
        model: model,
        speed: speed,
        radar: radar,
        describeFighterAircraft: describeFighterAircraft
    });
}
</script>
```

## Better concatenative prototypal inheritance using mixins

Crockford's method of concatenative prototypal inheritance has a lot of repetition. An alternative is:

```js
var aircraft = mixin({
    describeAircraft: function () {
        alert("The " + this.model + " flies at " + this.speed + " speed.");
    }
});

var fighterAircraft = mixin(aircraft, {
    describeFighterAircraft: function () {
        this.describeAircraft();
        alert("It has a " + this.radar + " radar signature.");
    }
});

var superFlanker = fighterAircraft({
    model: "Super Flanker",
    speed: "Mach 2.25",
    radar: "low"
});

superFlanker.describeFighterAircraft();
```

```html
<script>
function mixin() {
    var length = arguments.length;
    var index  = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var properties = arguments[index++];
        for (var name in properties)
            constructor[name] = properties[name];
    }

    return Object.freeze(constructor);

    function constructor(object) {
        for (var name in constructor)
            object[name] = constructor[name];
        return Object.freeze(object);
    }
}
</script>
```

## Using mixins without `this`

Yes, you can use mixins without using `this`. However, I don't see why you would want to:

```js
var aircraft = mixin({
    describeAircraft: function (aircraft) {
        alert("The " + aircraft.model + " flies at " +
            aircraft.speed + " speed.");
    }
});

var fighterAircraft = mixin(aircraft, {
    describeFighterAircraft: function (fighterAircraft) {
        fighterAircraft.describeAircraft();
        alert("It has a " + fighterAircraft.radar + " radar signature.");
    }
});

var superFlanker = fighterAircraft({
    model: "Super Flanker",
    speed: "Mach 2.25",
    radar: "low"
});

superFlanker.describeFighterAircraft();
```

```html
<script>
function mixin() {
    var length = arguments.length;
    var index  = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var properties = arguments[index++];
        for (var name in properties)
            constructor[name] = properties[name];
    }

    return Object.freeze(constructor);

    function constructor(object) {
        for (var name in constructor) {
            var value    = constructor[name];
            object[name] = typeof value === "function" ?
                value.bind(null, object) : value;
        }

        return Object.freeze(object);
    }
}
</script>
```

## Advantages of concatenative inheritance

There are many reasons to prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

1. Simple multiple inheritance.
2. Faster property access.

The only disadvantage that I can think of is that if the prototype is modified then the change will not be reflected on its instances. However, there's no good reason to change the prototype anyway. Hence, my mixins are all frozen.

Comment: Is it possible to use a mixin pattern without using `this`? Crockford's approach avoids both `this` and `new` and I'd like to be able to achieve that as well.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible. I updated my answer to show how. However, I don't see any reason to do so. What's wrong with using `this`?

Comment: In general, nothing, I use it plenty. But my current project is ad software and I'd like to try following the [AdSafe](http://www.adsafe.org/) guidelines (as well as trying to move to a more functional programming practice in order to correct some _undesirable_ programming habits of my coworkers.)