# Why are many people against the concept ES6 Class in JS?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I shifted to node.js from C# for the backend of my web application. In C#, I really like concept of OOP because it really makes the programs vivid by defining the relations between different classes. In node.js I want to use OOP as well and I plan to try out the new syntax class in ES6. However, when I read blogs online, I find there are quite number of people against the concept of class violently.

Some of the reasons are:

1. class in ES6 is not really class like other OOP language. It is still a type of function.
2. It will make newcomer confused between class and type.
3. JavaScript is designed to be functional.

These reasons does not really convince me that it is a bad idea of using classes in JS. But I wonder why are there so many people very concerned with it?

Comment: None of #1-3 is 100% true. "But I wonder why are there so many people very concerned with it?" --- don't bother, just have your own opinion and write your code in a way comfortable to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Douglas Crockford on Class Free OOP in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595749/douglas-crockford-on-class-free-oop-in-javascript)

Comment: "OOP" can be done without classes. JS objects implement state and behaviour (properties and methods), so you don't *need* classes. But if you like the new `class` syntax, just go ahead and use it.

Comment: @nnnnnn But isn't it very verbose when you want to implement inheritance?

Comment: @ShaohuaHuang those are syntax details. Your question covers the generic concepts, not how concise/verbose some language constructs are.

Comment: @zerkms: But I think the verbose of implementing inheritance in ES5 is the main reason ES6 comes up with Class Syntax. And from programmers' perspective, it is a very good thing as it makes code neat. However. from linguist's perspective, it makes javascript obscure in its syntax.

Comment: Well, I like ES2015 classes and use them. Your question is about why other people don't like it, which is opinion-based.